# Android java.io.IOException with audio streaming

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I am running audioplayer in streaming by using webservices I am getting IOException

```
08-19 09:24:54.235: WARN/System.err(394): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x64
08-19 09:24:54.235: WARN/System.err(394):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
08-19 09:24:54.235: WARN/System.err(394):     at com.sparsh.xavier.media.activity.AudioPlayerActivity$6$1.run(AudioPlayerActivity.java:183)
08-19 09:24:54.295: WARN/System.err(394):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-19 09:24:54.295: WARN/System.err(394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 09:24:54.295: WARN/System.err(394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-19 09:24:54.295: WARN/System.err(394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-19 09:24:54.295: WARN/System.err(394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 09:24:54.295: WARN/System.err(394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-19 09:24:54.295: WARN/System.err(394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-19 09:24:54.295: WARN/System.err(394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-19 09:24:54.295: WARN/System.err(394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 09:24:55.075: ERROR/AudioService(68): Media server died.
```

I have the above error when I am using below url
http://cdnbakmi.kaltura.com/p/672322/sp/67232200/raw/entry_id/0_281db5u2/version/0

but execute my application with out any errors when I am trying with sample url http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/tutorials/audio.mp3

I write bellow code for my application

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.reset();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioURL);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

please tell me is this problem with my coding or with providing url.

thanks in advance.

**edit:**
I solve this problem by using this code

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
String redirectUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
```

I get the redirect url by using above code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When it's not working with one server (and working for another) it means the problem is with the server (response) and not in your app. Try those links in browser first.

The failing link is redirecting to another URL that is actual MP3 URL. So you need to connect to the URL and get the response that may contain the actual mp3 URL.

I think this get the new URL.

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 urlConnection.getURL()// should give you the new URL dynamically created by server.
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I check with both url's in browser and, both are giving proper downloadble links in the browser.

Comment: edited my answer. I dont know how redirects work. But hope that helps solve your problem.

Comment: Is there any way to get redirect url?