# How to stream mp3 from shortened URL

Tags: android

I have an mp3 file in a shortened URL:

```
http://services.xyz.net/2_4/download?file=l9G0qe5b%2fiMDXhIGuvMhHg%3d&token=c371ae3c-ed65-4991-bbdc-bd2e5333116e
```

The file is not getting played if I use the shortened URL.  I am getting `IOExeception` in `MediaPlayer.prepare()` but if I put the file in public server and try to play using the fully qualified URL it plays. But the Blackberry and the iPhone are able to play the same song using the same shortened URL. I have a requirement to use the shortened URL. How to stream mp3 file and play for this type of shortened URL? If I put that shortend url in device browser then the file is getting downloaded from that place. This url is not redirecting to any other url. Also I have tested the same code works for some other shortened URL from the same server.

```
if(player!= null){
                player.stop();
                player.reset();
                player.release();
                player = null;
            }



            String url ="http://services.xyz.net/2_4/download?file=l9G0qe5b%2fiMDXhIGuvMhHg%3d&token=c371ae3c-ed65-4991-bbdc-bd2e5333116e";//for this not working

/*
String url = = http://203.123.181.194/downloads/sunil/Try.mp3;//here its working
*/

            System.out.println("....URL...."+url);

            player = new MediaPlayer();
            player.setDataSource(url);
            player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            player.prepare();
            player.start();
```

Comment: apparently, MediaPlayer doesn't handle redirects. The answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116947/android-java-io-ioexception-with-audio-streaming might help

Comment: @Gryphius, The link that you have mentioned would have worked if the url is redirecting. But in My case it doesn't redirect. If you put that url in browser then the file is getting download from there.

Comment: how exactly did you generate that shortened url? did you rename the file itself to a shorter name or did you use some sort of url shortener service? Or do you use a special script that reads the file from disk and forwards it to the client and maybe doesn't set the Content-Type ?

Comment: @Gryphius, I didnt do any thing. I am getting the shortend url from server.

Comment: @Gryphius, Also I have tried the solution provided in the link that you have provided, I am getting same error.